# How do you put a circle on top of an exponential symbol

Tags: accents

How do you put a circle on top of an exponential symbol
[image]

Comment: This might be `$\mathring{e_{x}}$`

Comment: @egreg The `ring` is shifted a little to the right.

Comment: Try `$\mathring{e}_{x}$`.